# Restart IIS on remote machine

Tags: iis

How can restart `IIS` on a remote machine?

I know the IP address and administrator user's user name and password information.

I am using `C#` and `ASP .NET 2.0`.

Answer (score 57):

Simplest will be `iisreset <servername>`

Run command prompt as admin and execute the command.

Example : If server name is SRVAPP then command will be `iisreset SRVAPP`

Comment: if iisreset commadn is not available  use _"Turn Windows Featrures On or Off"_ to install _IIS > Web Management Tools >> IIS Management Console_ (https://www.howtogeek.com/112455/how-to-install-iis-8-on-windows-8/)

Comment: Fails with error: Access denied, you must be an administrator of the remote computer

Comment: This used to work for me, but back in 2020, but I get the access denied error when running the same command now.

Answer (score 16):

I tried the PowerShell-based method but I kept getting the following error:

`Connecting to remote server <TARGET-HOST> failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request.`

I finally found out that I needed to add the target node as a `TrustedHosts` in the source node and vice-versa. If you run into that same issue, you can fix it by opening an elevated **Command Prompt** and typing the following commands:

**From the PC you'll use to issue the commands:**

```
powershell
winrm set winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="TARGET-HOST"}'
```

**From the destination PC** (the one with IIS):

```
powershell
winrm set winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="SOURCE-HOST"}'
```

(replacing `TARGET-HOST` and `SOURCE-HOST` with your servers *hostnames* or IP addresses). As soon as you do that you can issue any remote **PowerShell** command, such as:

**IIS Stop:**

```
powershell invoke-command -computername "TARGET-HOST" -scriptblock {iisreset /STOP}
```

**IIS Start:**

```
powershell invoke-command -computername "TARGET-HOST" -scriptblock {iisreset /START}
```

**IIS Restart:**

```
powershell invoke-command -computername "TARGET-HOST" -scriptblock {iisreset /RESTART}
```

... and more.

For an extensive review of this issue you can also [read this post](http://www.ryadel.com/en/start-stop-and-restart-iis-from-a-remote-pc/) on my blog.

Comment: Do we have something with TFS task to do IIS reset on the target agent?

Answer (score 5):

You could use sc, as Thomas Franke suggested:

```
sc \\RemoteServer stop iisadmin
sc \\RemoteServer start w3svc
```

or SysInternals' [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx). The [PsTools suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx) is useful for these scenarios.

```
psexec \\RemoteServer iisreset
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the "sc" command in order to control the iis-service on the remote machine.

```
sc \\RemoteServer stop [iis-service-name]
```

Use

```
sc help
```

in order to get a list of possible arguments.

Also take a look at [a microsoft kb-article on your subject](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B166819&x=7&y=12).

Answer (score 0):

The following POSH script will allow you to asynchronously reset a set of machines remotely (very handy when working with a large set):

```
$a = Get-Content "c:\OneMachineNamePerLine.txt"

foreach($line in $a)
{

    Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
        iisreset $line
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

How remote is remote? You could just execute [Shutdown.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317371) from your c# code? If that's not possible (firewalls etc) then the next best would probably be putting a service on there that you could call remotely (and securely!) that shuts the machine down.

Comment: this describes how to remotely shut down a _server_ rather than restart solely the _service_