# Is it possible to execute bat file to stop iis on remote server

Tags: batch-file, iis, remote-server

I would like my build server to stop iis on the target machine, copy files then start iis.  I would like to NOT use powershell.

I was thinking that I could put a stop iis bat file on the target machine and have jenkins run it.  But I'm not sure if that would work.

Is this possible, and if not is there some other way to do this with out using powershell?

Thanks
r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.  Use `wmic`.

```
wmic /node:servername /user:domain\admin /password:adminpass service where 'name="W3SVC" or name="iisadmin"' call stopservice
:: copy files
wmic /node:servername /user:domain\admin /password:adminpass service where 'name="W3SVC" or name="iisadmin"' call startservice
```

I think that's right, anyway.  I don't have IIS installed, so I'm not positive about the service name.

Or if the context from which this script runs on the build server already has admin rights on the remote server, you could just use

```
sc \\servername stop W3SVC
sc \\servername stop IISadmin
```

etc.  Do `sc /?` and `wmic service /?` for more information.  Consider the risks of hard coding a domain admin username and pass into a text batch file, of course.

**Edit:** [Some people suggest](http://forums.asp.net/t/311203.aspx?Is+there+a+way+to+stop+and+start+the+IIS+server+from+command+prompt) that the best way to stop / start IIS is with `iisreset.exe`.  So try

```
iisreset servername /stop
:: copy stuff
iisreset servername /start
```

This might be a better question for ServerFault.  It's not really a coding question.

Also, this question [appears to be a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704429/restart-iis-on-remote-machine).