# How to perform IISReset on multiple remote server using .NET Core?

Tags: c#, powershell, asp.net-core, iis, automation

I'm creating a website and in it I'm giving a link where the user enters his/her Azure VM username and password and then I'm gonna go ahead and restart the machine IIS server.

So I'm writing a .NET Code for implementing the same but no luck yet. I'm not able to restart the IIS server for the remote machines, I have even looked for an alternative approach to achieve the same using Powershell but unable to do so.

I tried remotely restarting the IIS server using WMI and also created code for calling Powershell in .Net Core but I'm not able to achieve the same.

Can someone please help me with how to restart the IIS server remotely using C# code or .NET Core code?

Comment: Restarting services on local or remote hosts is a very common PowerShell thing and is well documented in the PowerShell help files and via plenty of resources online. Just search for 'starting / stopping service on remote computers'. YOu can call PowerShell code from C# and other languages. Just search for 'Running PowerShell scripts from C#' or 'Running PowerShell code from C#'. You'll get plenty of examples. Jump on Youtube to see how. You are asking folks here to write code for you. Folks tell you, this is not a free code writing service. You need to show your efforts and errors.

Comment: @postanote Share me the link wherein there is a PowerShell script that restarts IIS on a remote server using the system credentials.

Answer (score 0):

As for this...

> Share me the link wherein there is a PowerShell script that restarts
>   IIS on a remote server using the system credentials.

... a quick search using ['Restart IIS on remote machine'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%27Restart%20IIS%20on%20remote%20machine%27&form=ANNTH1&refig=3c8313268e724764bd122e73b84990e0&sp=-1&pq=%27restart%20iis%20on%20remote%20machine%27&sc=1-31&qs=n&sk=&cvid=3c8313268e724764bd122e73b84990e0)

... will give a list of articles in the topic, some from right here on StackOverflow, since this is not the first time this has been asked. So, your question can be considered a potential duplicate of the below.

Example(s):

> [about_Remote - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote)
>
> [Restart IIS on remote machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704429/restart-iis-on-remote-machine)

Some of the answers, not using PowerShell to do this from the above are:

```
# Simplest will be 
iisreset <servername>
# Run command prompt as admin and execute the command.
# Example : If server name is SRVAPP then command will be iisreset SRVAPP

# You could use sc

sc \\RemoteServer stop iisadmin
sc \\RemoteServer start w3svc
# or SysInternals' psexec. The PsTools suite is useful for these scenarios.

psexec \\RemoteServer iisreset
```

PowerShell Remoting requires you to be in the local admin group on the target host. You cannot run PowerShell code as SYSTEM unless you are running a scheduled task, even then it is the scheduled task running as whatever credential it was set for and running any script in that task. To run PowerShell code as another user, you must know the username and password.

You can use PowerShell to set up a scheduled task to run. Just search for ['PowerShell scheduled task'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%27PowerShell%20scheduled%20task%27&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=%27powershell%20scheduled%20task%27&sc=8-27&sk=&cvid=8DF59445AC3B4159B8A36872766FC74D) for details.

Comment: I would like to connect with you and discuss this further, please let me know how I can reach you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. I tried the below codes for restarting IIS remotely but it didn't work.

Method 1:

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Management;
using System.IO;
using System.Security;


Process myProcess = new Process();

ProcessStartInfo remoteAdmin =
            new ProcessStartInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), "iisreset.exe"));
            remoteAdmin.Arguments = "/restart";

myProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";

var s = new SecureString();
//s.AppendChar('g');

 Console.WriteLine("Enter username:");          
 string userName = Console.ReadLine();

 Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);

 Console.WriteLine("Enter password:");
 string password = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);

var securePasswordString = new SecureString();
// Use ToCharArray to convert string to array.
char[] array = password.ToCharArray();

// Loop through array.
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    // Get character from the array.
    securePasswordString.AppendChar(array[i]);            
}

remoteAdmin.UserName = userName;
remoteAdmin.Password = securePasswordString;
remoteAdmin.Domain = "localhost";
myProcess.StartInfo = remoteAdmin;
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

myProcess.Start(); //---ERROR HERE

if (!myProcess.Start())
{
    // That didn't work
    Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
    Console.WriteLine("Process did not start!!!");
}

myProcess.WaitForExit();

var processExitCode = myProcess.ExitCode;

if (processExitCode == 0)
{
   Console.WriteLine("The operation completed successfully.");
}

if (processExitCode != 0)
{
   // That didn't work
   if (processExitCode == 5)
      {
         Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
         Console.WriteLine("Access Denied");
      }

}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Method 2:

```cs
ConnectionOptions conn = new ConnectionOptions();
conn.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;         
conn.Username = @"Username";
conn.Password = "";

//ManagementScope theScope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + txtServerName.Text + "\\root\\cimv2", conn);

theScope.Connect();  //---ERROR HERE
```

2. I tried the below code to run powershell script from C# code but I need the script which takes remote server admin credentials and restart the IIS.

```cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

static void RunPsScriptMethod2()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    PowerShell psExec = PowerShell.Create();
    psExec.AddCommand(@"C:\Users\d92495j\Desktop\test.ps1");
    psExec.AddArgument(DateTime.Now);

    Collection<PSObject> results;
    Collection<ErrorRecord> errors;
    results = psExec.Invoke();
    errors = psExec.Streams.Error.ReadAll();

    if (errors.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (ErrorRecord error in errors)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(error.ToString());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (PSObject result in results)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(result.ToString());
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
}
```